# Why am I doing badly on the html5 test?

Tags: firefox, html

The version of Firefox in the 10.10 repos seems to perform pretty poorly on the [HTML5 test](http://html5test.com/). Why is this? Is there something I can do about that? Does it matter?

Comment: What is "poorly"? Give a number. Also note that (as far as I know anyway) the Firefox version in the 10.10 repo still is Firefox 3.6 and not Firefox 4 (which is still in beta). I'd advice you to add the version number of your firefox to your question (Help -> About).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Firefox 3.6 doesn’t support all the html5 specifications, no browser today does. Look at http://html5readiness.com/ which browser supports what features. No it doesn’t matter a whole lot, html5 is still in the development stages.